# How to get image name in django without extension name

Tags: django, django-templates

How can i get image name without extension name

I'm using this code but output= imagename.jpg .

```
{{ post.image.name }}
```

I want like this output=imagename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain such name with [**`os.path.splitext`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to split a filename in the "root" and the "extension". But you of course do not have access to that in the Django template. But you can define a *template filter*.

In your app, you can define such template filter, in a file in a module named `templatetags`, for example `ospath.py`:

```
# app/templatetags/ospath.py

from os.path import splitext

from django import template


register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def noext(value):
    return splitext(value)[0]
```

In your template, you then can load the template tags with `{% load ospath %}`, and then use the `noext` template filter:

```
{% load ospath %}

{{ post.image.name|noext }}
```

Note however that an extension is just the part after the last dot. Some files have no extension, except if that dot is the first character of the filename. There is no *official* list of extensions.

Comment: @Enes: why would it be unsafe? The library itself is not unsafe (it is even a standard library, so it is already available). The `os.path.splitext`, does not make OS calls, it is text processing.

Comment: @Enes: you can look up the source code here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ntpath.py#L195